# variant significant digits on siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I'm trying to several TeX packages about settings of significant digits  to edit textbooks.
In siunitx package, I would like to set the effective digits to 2 digits and not to use 10 ^ 1, 10 ^ 0, 10 ^ -1.
It means, I wamt to display as follows:

```
2.0×10^2,   20,   2.0,   0.20,   2.0×10^-2
```

instead of

```
2×10^2   2.0×10^1,   2,   2×10^-1,   2×10^-2.
```

My code as follows:

```
\documentclass{jsarticle}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\sisetup{
    scientific-notation = true,
    round-mode = figures,
    round-precision = 2,
}
    ¥SI{200}{¥cm}    
    ¥SI{20}{¥cm}
    ¥SI{2}{¥cm}
    ¥SI{0.2}{¥cm}
    ¥SI{0.02}{¥cm}

¥end{document}
```

Do you have any ideas to improve?

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Thank you very much, samcarter. I re-edit my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    scientific-notation =true,
    round-mode = places,
    round-precision = 1,
    }

\begin{document}
\num{200} 

\num[scientific-notation=false]{20}

\num{2}

\num[scientific-notation=false]{0.2}

\num[round-integer-to-decimal]{0.02}

\end{document}
```

[image]